# How do I use jigsaw blocks to make random mazes?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have recently discovered jigsaw blocks and was going to use them to make a randomly generated maze. However I am unfamiliar with the interface or how it works. I have also heard that I can save structures with a structure block and use them in the jigsaw block for said maze but I don't know how to use the block.